# Focus method is not working zk

Tags: java, focus, zk

i'm new in ZK.
when Listbox is rendered dynamicly, the method focus() is not working.

this is my zul:

```
<textbox id="productionText" width="170px" xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client">
    <attribute w:name="onOK">
        <![CDATA[                   
            zk.afterMount(function () { 
                $('#listOfProduction').first().focus();
                });
        ]]>
    </attribute>
    </textbox>
    <listbox id="listOfProduction" >

</listbox>
```

this is my Java class

```
@Listen("onChange=#productionText")
public void setprodactionSearchString(@ContextParam(ContextType.TRIGGER_EVENT) InputEvent even) {
    String valueOFSearch = even.getValue();
    if (valueOFSearch.length() > 3) {
        listProduction = templatesService.getProductionSitesList(valueOFSearch);

        for (int i = 0; i < listProduction.size(); i++) {
            Listitem listItem = new Listitem();
            listItem.setValue(listProduction.get(i)[0]);
            listItem.setLabel(listProduction.get(i)[1].toString());
            listItem.setParent(listOfProduction);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks
a lot

Comment: Not working... how? Throws an exception?

Comment: @ Andy Turner there is no exeption. i want cursor to stay on first position of listbox, after "onOK" event in textbox, but now cursor stays on texbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am more inclined on using the MVVM aproach so here's my working code sample. Type more than four letters on the textbox:

[Focus to Listbox's first element](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/10b19cd/1-Textbox-search-and-focus-to-listbox)

PS: if you take a look at the code, you'll see that I make even a setSelectedIndex. I think is what you want